# Creating a Templated Workbook from Every Row of a Data Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data sheet with names, IDs, etc. in a spreadsheet. I also have a separate workbook that I'd like to use as a template. The data in the cells will have to go in specific cells (not together) on the template workbook.

I need this process to happen for each row of data, meaning each row should create a new workbook from the template and populate the appropriate cells.

I've tried a few different methods but can't get very far. I was think I could loop by row, but I get hung up on having multiple columns and having them get copied all over the template.

Any idea what the best method is, or if this is even possible?

Edit: I am trying this code and getting this error. Can't figure out how to correct.[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbbir.png)

Comment: Always best to post the code you tried and describe exactly what problem(s) you had when trying to run it.  Questions without code tend to get closed here.

Comment: I will be honest, I don't know enough for the code to have looked anywhere near like it should, so I didn't think it would be helpful. Just trying to fill the request of my employer. It's not my field at all.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a data sheet like you described:

[image: Data to be used.]

And a template workbook, where name needs to be entered in cell B3 in Sheet1 & ID in cell C4 in Sheet2.

You'd need to open both the data file and the template file, and try something like the following:

```
Sub moving_data()

Dim No_Of_Rows As Integer
Dim DataFile As String
Dim Template As String

DataFile = "Master Data.xlsm" '<< Change
Template = "Template workbook.xlsx" '<< Change

Workbooks(DataFile).Activate
'Count number of rows
No_Of_Rows = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To No_Of_Rows
    'Iterate through the columns of Data File
    Workbooks(DataFile).Activate
    Let Copyrange = "A" & i
    Range(Copyrange).Copy
    'Paste where you need to paste
    Workbooks(Template).Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    'Second column, and so on
    Workbooks(DataFile).Activate
    Copyrange = "B" & i
    Range(Copyrange).Copy
    'Paste where you need to paste
    Workbooks(Template).Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("C4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    'Save Template
    Template = "Template workbook " & i & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Template
Next i

End Sub
```